# Why would a batch file application (which runs dll) have different resolution when run on VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, batch-file, resolution, user-interface, dll

Hello Everyone I am new to this platform and I am in the learning curve (dll or batch files). I have an application created by a third party which contains bunch of dll's and a windows batch file which i think run through all of these to start application or GUI.

The third party company has sent a new GUI , please note there is no difference in functionality.

When I run this batch file on my local machine everything works the way it should but when I run the same thing on a windows VM the resolution is a bit odd and makes the application unusable.
Please refer the next 2 pictures.

When installed on your own laptop resolution is perfect and usable (i have used chrome as an example not the actual application):

[image: When installed on your own laptop resolution is perfect and usable (i have used chrome as an example not the actual application)]

This happens when the application is installed on VM, the resolution is not perfect and cause issue with the usability of the application:
[image: This happens when the application is installed on VM, the resolution is not perfect and cause issue with the usability of the application]

Please note:- both my host computer and VM are using windows 10, .NET Desktop Runtime 6.0 x64.

Since I require to get this application on VM so we can do testing on this, what could be causing this issue and how can it be resolved?

I am fairly new so I am waiting on suggestions to try and resolve this.

Comment: Have you asked the "third party"?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, they simply say that we couldn't run this on a VM. I simply don't believe its a complicated issue and can be resolved with right drivers or something.